# Sound over bluetooth to transit to several blueooth headsets

Tags: sound, bluetooth, headset

I would like to watch movies using Ubuntu PC, and use a bluetooth USB adapter (it's a desktop PC) as the sound output. Then if two or more people come, they can connect with their stereo bluetooth headsets to the PC and can listen to the same sound. Is this possible to setup in Ubuntu?. If yes, then how exactly?

Comment: I doubt you will get what you need for two reasons: 1) Bluetooth audio transmission always has a delay too long for watching movies. 2) you will most likely not be able to connect to more than one headset at a time because BT needs to be paired to a sepcific device, and in addition bandwith is limited.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards